# How to block R from accessing the internet using a firewall?

Tags: r, security, rstudio, firewall

I am trying to install R on a machine but I do not want it to upload or download from the internet.  What should I block through the firewall?

Comment: I don't think R provides any mechanism for limiting connection, so this needs to be resolved outside of R and RStudio. You will need to provide your OS and if you have any firewall software currently installed, since the resolution to your question will reside *there*.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you want to prevent from accessing the internet? I'm not sure firewall settings would be sufficient. You can use R to execute system commands. Your best bet would probably be a docker container [without internet access](https://serverfault.com/a/892242).